# Is there a more detailed specification on the behavior of contenteditable?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, firefox, browser

I find  [the W3C specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#attr-contenteditable) but it's not quite in detail. For example, it has no description on what element should be inserted after the user types `Enter`.

Is there a more detailed reference on `contenteditable` if such fulfillments are determined by the browsers?

I scanned the docs of Chromium and Firefox but failed to find one. QAQ

(Simply making a trial may work temporarily. But in case of some bizarre conditions, a mantained doc would be great.)

Comment: For implementation? or use? MDN's offering: [Making content editable: How does it work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content#how_does_it_work)

Comment: And specific to your question about `Enter`: [Differences In Markup Generation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content#differences_in_markup_generation)

Comment: @fnostro Thanks. The page really offers something. So I conclude as the following:  The caret is (and must be) in an innermost block element `X`. By typing `Enter`, a new same block element is created to contain the contents (including elements) after the caret (of course in `X`).  When an element (except the newly created `X`) is blank, it's deleted. This explains the fact that if the caret is at the start/end of an inline element, then the inline element won't be kept in the original/new `X` element (this `X` is filled with a <br>). Is this true?

Comment: @fnostro  Would you like to post an answer? Otherwise, would you mind if I post my comment as an answer?

Comment: @fnostro To clarify: The previous comment applies for the case where **`X` is one of the descendants of a contenteditable element**. Otherwise, if the `X` itself is the outermost contenteditable element, then `<div>` is always created.

Comment: You can inspect (via browser dev tools) the simple editor on the above link near the top to see what's actually being inserted when you select `Enter`. And it's configurable.  By default it creates a new `div`, but you can configure it to use a simple `<br>`. But be aware: `execCommand` is deprecated.  As for posting an answer, meh, I'm not overly concerned about rep scores :) Have at it. Happy coding!

Comment: @fnostro Well, the previous comments are just from my limited inspections. But I'm not sure if there would be some exceptional cases. (So I'm trying to find a "relatively complete guideline for contenteditable") Thank you anyway.  It seems what we know is enough for now.